# Xml Schema латинские символы в HEX формате

Tags: xml, xsd

Как в схеме описать условие, что текст в элементе всегда состоит из одной буквы латинского алфавита входящей в HEX формат.

```xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:attribute name="C">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:length value="4"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:attribute>
  <xs:element name="A">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="B">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute ref="C" use="required" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="D">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute ref="C" use="required" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: А что значит "из одной буквы латинского алфавита", т.е. в после может быть всего одна буква или в поле может быть сколько угодно букв (или может быть фиксированное число, или от одной до n), но одних и тех же?

Comment: @StateItPrimitive в поле(в названии элемента) всего может быть всего 1 буква, она обязательно латинская и обязательно входит в HEX формат. Можно ли просто прописать от А до F или есть специальный тип данных для данной манипуляции?

Comment: Раз вам требуется в имени элемента, то придется только если через `xs:choice` (причем придется в явном виде перечислить все варианты по одному, т.к. в данном элементе нельзя указывать лишь формат строки).

Comment: @StateItPrimitve спасибо за совет! 

На самом деле, не соображу как это сделать через xs:choise. Если можете на примере - будет круто!

Comment: Попробуйте [вот так](https://jsfiddle.net/573tgbqc/3/), например.

Comment: @StateItPrimitve В ComplexType extension и choice по синтаксису ставить вместе нельзя. Соответственно добавить в уже существующий элемент не получится. Если выносить отдельно, то непонятно как сделать reference.
Если выносить отдельно, то в дереве они отображаются как дополнительные элементы(что в общем-то логично, но не верно)
Как быть? Бьюсь полдня уже :)

Comment: Я сам в этом не эксперт, поэтому если завтра никто так и не предложит решения, то я попробую вечерком после работы как следует поковыряться и попробовать найти способ решения :)

Comment: Такс, у меня тут только сейчас выдалось времечко. Посмотрел я, и обнаружил, что элемент `choice` можно использовать в связке с элементом `extension`, но для этого их необходимо использовать внутри `complexContent`, а не `simpleContent` (правда в качестве `base` придется использовать какой-нибудь `complexType`, а не просто `xs:string`, но там обернуть тот же `xs:string` в `complexType` можно просто, если я правильно понимаю). [Тестируемый пример](https://jsfiddle.net/g1rg9hfq/).

Answer (score 0):

Например, так

```
<xsd:element name="hex1">
  <xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="A"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="B"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="C"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="D"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="E"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="F"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

Или так

```
<xsd:element name="hex2">
  <xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:pattern value="[A-Fa-f]"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```